# Under which circumstances can I have " no net reputation changes on this day"

Tags: support, reputation-history

I've seen this line in my reputation tab where I had **0** rep change.
In the details it's only written:

> There were no net reputation changes on this day

I wonder in which cases this happens?

What is the difference with a day with no rep change that is usually not logged?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Any time someone votes on one of your posts (up, down, or accept) but then *undoes* the vote, and that was the *only change in that day*, the log will show that you had no reputation changes.  The same applies when you downvote another answer, then undo that vote.

That's because there was, however briefly, a vote recorded there.

If you are looking at someone else's profile, then there are more reasons for the message to be displayed. In addition to votes undone, there may be entries you are not allowed to see, such as downvotes on other posts (not undone) and deleted post events.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer! If it's the only reason, maybe it would have been simpler to write something like `a vote has been cancelled` :)

Comment: @alain.janinm: I can't think of any other reasons *right now*, but it could also be the developers kept their options open.

Comment: Hail the mighty developers and their secrets then! Thanks again

Comment: Accept and unaccept should also fall into this case.

Comment: @psubsee2003: I see those as a kind of vote too, but I can make that more explicit. Another reputation-change-by-vote is downvoting someone else's answer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this message also gets used when you're viewing *someone else's* profile and there are actually events there, just none that you can see. For example, removed posts, or downvotes they've cast. Since only that user can see those events, they'd be hidden from you and you'd be shown an essentially blank day.

Comment: @animuson: good point, I only addressed the case where you are looking at your own.