# Discrepancy between total and detail in my reputation log

Tags: support, reputation-history

I was having a look at my reputation history, and I have seen that I have a -15 on April 21st this year. In order to know what happened that day I expanded the section and noticed a message saying:

> "There were no net reputation changes on this day"

[image: Reputation log detail]

So I expected the total to be 0 and not -15 (as mentioned in [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283388/under-which-circumstances-can-i-have-no-net-reputation-changes-on-this-day) where the user saw a line on the log for a day where apparently nothing happened).

Is this -15 change accounted in my total reputation? Even if it is not related to any downvote?

Comment: It is the kind of rep correction you'd get when the answer mark was removed from one of your posts.  Either because the questioner unmarked it or because the Q+A was deleted.  Seems it got deleted really well :)  Go to stackoverflow.com/reputation, it might show the postid.

Comment: [Blame caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/)

Comment: There is an unaccept there on a deleted post, which you can see by checking the box next to "show removed posts" at the bottom of your history.